# Conditional linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

What would be the best approach for converting this SQL to linq?

I've earlier made views in the database based on such an sql, and then query the view with linq. But I've would like to know if there are other approaches.

The SQL finds the assigned object for an task. The task table contains three foreign key columns, as the assigned to may be from Department, Position or a Person. Only one is allowed.

SQL:

```
SELECT   id,
         title,
         assigned_to = (case
            when idAssignedDepartment is not null then (select description from department where id = idAssignedDepartment)
            when idAssignedPosition is not null then (select description from position where id = idAssignedPosition )
            when idAssignedPerson is not null then (select fullname from person where id = idAssignedPerson )               
            end)
FROM     task
```

Using LinqToEF

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. What flavor of linq are you using? L2E, L2S, L2D? You should post some c# code of what you have and what you would like to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
var q = from t in task
        from dep in department.Where(x => x.id == t.idAssignedDepartment).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from pos in position.Where(x => x.id == t.idAssignedPosition).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from per in person .Where(x => x.id == t.idAssignedPerson).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            t.id,
            t.title,
            assigned_to = t.idAssignedDepartment != null ? dep.description :
                          t.idAssignedPosition != null ? pos.description :
                          t.idAssignedPerson != null ? per.fullname : 
                          null
        };
```

Comment: Though I get a NotSupportedException: Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Comment: @Kman does your query look exactly like this or did you make any additions?

Comment: It looks exactly like this, it seems that when I add more than one "from" in the query, I get this exception.

Comment: are all the datasources (task, department...) tables in the database? You usually get this error when you try to compare a two complex objects. I assume `idAssignedDepartment` and `t.Id` are primitive types?

Comment: Yes, they are there. I am able to query them "isolated". The id's are all integers. However, I am running this through LinqPad and not from a actual project.

Comment: If I instead use the relations through EF, pos = task.dep.description it seems to work. So I just recreate the query that way. I'll check your answer as resolved :) Thanx